# How to edit indented codes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, scope, indentation

Kinda new to python, coming from a C/C++ development experience. Not to rant, but the indentation and spacing things are kinda becoming the bane of my life. So here is the problem. Take this code snippet, typed sequentially, never erasing or inserting any edit between existing codes.

```
while condition:
    line 1
    line 2

line3 #outside the loop
```

It is working fine. But, suppose, I want to add another instruction inside the loop. (Editing using jupyter notebook and sublime, on Linux) So I add the line as

```
while condition:
    line 1
    line 1.5
    line 2

line3 #outside the loop
```

That is when the problem starts. No matter what I try, I can never make it work. It is giving me errors like

> line 2
>       ^
>   IndentationError: unexpected indent

or some variations depending on the circumstances. It seems somehow adding a single line within a large and complicated nested block structure somehow totally messes up the whole thing.

I do not insert the spaces/indents manually, I just let my editor take care of that. When I hit enter, the cursor moves down to the next line, indented at the same level as the previous line (unless the previous line ends with a *:*, in which case it adds another indentation).

When I need to end a *while* loop or *if* block, I just hit the backspace to retract one indentation level. The blocks look perfectly okay by eye inspection, but have no clue how the interpreter *sees* it.

Any help, on what am I doing wrong, or at least what are the good practices to avoid this problem? Particularly, adding even a single line within an existing nested block seems nigh impossible.

Comment: Is your editor inserting spaces, or tabs? It makes a difference. As far as *good practices*, you can find recommendations and suggestions at [python.org](http://www.python.org).

Comment: Can you give us the exact code that's not working? Your examples are theoretically correct but in practice you could be doing something wrong

Comment: Can you open the python script inside a plain editor to see the actual spaces/tabs?

Comment: Your editor is inserting tabs where there should be spaces, or vice versa. PEP8 recommends using spaces, so configure your editor to expand tabs to spaces.

Comment: Can you configure your editor to show tabs as visible characters?  That should at least make it obvious if it's mixing tabs/spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You may mix of using space and tab indentation. You can use either tab or space but not both. However,  it's recommend to use space as The PEP8 Python Style Guide

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can install `pylint` extension to easily detect such kind of these errors. Something like this:

[pylint output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaEPt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime text editor uses tabs for indentation by default. If you initially used spaces for indentation and edit later, you would have a mix of both spaces and tabs for indentation, which is what is causing the indentation error. This is because Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.

The [PEP8 Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) recommends using 4 spaces per indentation level. Go back and replace the tabs with spaces, and the code will work just fine.

(PS: It's easy enough to change the default indentation settings for Sublime)